# Magento 2 Add Bundled Product to Cart Programmatically

Tags: magento2, cart, magento-2.0, bundled-product, bundle

I'm trying to figure out how to **add a bundled product to cart programmatically** in Magento 2 with custom options.

In Magento 1 I could achieve it with the following

```
$params = array(
    'product' => 14,
    'related_product' => null,
    'bundle_option' => array(
        13 => 23,
        20 => 24,
        14 => 25,
        16 => array(
            0 => 21,
            1 => 12,
        ),
    ),
    'options' => array(
        5 => 'Some Test value to a text field',
    ),
    'qty' => 1,
);

$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');

$product = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product();
$product->load(14);

$cart->addProduct($product, $params);
$cart->save();

Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
```

Comment: Have you found solutios?

Comment: Still working on it. I haven't had a chance to test out Raphael's approach yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reckon the right way of doing it would be the following:

First you need to inject the following classes to your class constructor:

```
protected $_cart;

protected $_productRepository;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository
) {
    $this->_cart = $cart;
    $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
    ...
}
```

Then you can use the following code:

```
$params = [
    'product' => 14,
    'related_product' => null,
    'bundle_option' => [
        13 => 23,
        20 => 24,
        14 => 25,
        16 => [
            0 => 21,
            1 => 12,
        ],
    ],
    'options' => [
        5 => 'Some Test value to a text field',
    ],
    'qty' => 1
];

$product = $this->_productRepository->getById(14);

$this->_cart->addProduct($product, $params);
$this->_cart->save();
```

Comment: Hi Raphael, what are these  'bundle_option' => [
        13 => 23,
        20 => 24,
        14 => 25,
        16 => [
            0 => 21,
            1 => 12,
        ],
    ],           can you explain them..?

Comment: is it bundled items id's or what..?

Comment: can you update the answer like without hard code?

Comment: can you please tell me what the meaning of below array from bundle options
16 => [
     0 => 21,
     1 => 12,
 ]

Comment: @Raphael How can i assign custom price for child bundle product ?

Comment: How can use it in phtml in add to cart button

Comment: you use hard-coded value how can I understand what is bundle options?

Answer (score 3):

Below you can find my code to how i resolve it, you have to use field selection_id and not sub product id (in this case i use only one multiselect option):

```
// get selection option in a bundle product
$selectionCollection = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)
                       ->getSelectionsCollection(
$_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getOptionsIds($_product),$_product);
// create bundle option
$cont = 0;
$selectionArray = [];
foreach ($selectionCollection as $proselection){                        
            $selectionArray[$cont] = $proselection->getSelectionId();
            $cont++;
        }
// get options ids 
$optionsCollection = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)
            ->getOptionsCollection($_product);

foreach ($optionsCollection as $options) {
       $id_option = $options->getId();
            }             
// generate bundle_option array
$bundle_option = [$id_option => [$selectionArray]];

$params = [
            'product' => $id,
            'bundle_option' => $bundle_option,
            'qty' => 1
          ];                

$this->cart->addProduct($_product, $params);
```

The bundle_option results like below:

```
$bundle_option = array (9 =>  // this is option id
                   array (0 => // this is a simple counter
                     array (0 => '42', // 42 is selection_id
                            1 => '43', // 43 is second selection_id
                           ),
                         ),
                 )
```

I hope that i can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest a straight forward approach. It works weather you have set your bundle product options require or not required.

```
    $params = [
            'form_key' => $this->formKey->getFormKey(),
            'product' => $productId,
            'qty' => $productQty
    ];
    //get all the selection products used in bundle product.
    if('bundle' === $_product->getTypeId()){
            $selectionCollection = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)
            ->getSelectionsCollection(
                $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getOptionsIds($_product),
                $_product
            );
            foreach ($selectionCollection as $proselection) {
                $params['bundle_option'][$proselection->getOptionId()] = $proselection->getSelectionId();
            }
    }
    $this->cart->addProduct($_product, $params);
    $this->cart->save();
```