# How to add bundle product to cart programmatically with custom price and quantity (of all products) in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, custom-options, addtocart, programmatically, bundle-product

I am struggling with **Bundle Product add to cart** programmatically in Magento 2.

Here I need to add all products with **custom price and quantity** and I want to do this operation in Product **`list.phtml`** file.

Can you help me with this, please?

Comment: add your code. what you tried?

Comment: I just follow this article (http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112788/magento-2-add-bundled-product-to-cart-programmatically) but I did not understand what is what in this array ('bundle_option' => [
        13 => 23,
        20 => 24,
        14 => 25,
        16 => [
            0 => 21,
            1 => 12,
        ],
    ],)

Comment: If you done with this can you explain me the parameters and right process to add a bundle product to cart programmatically ?

Comment: is it working my solutions?

Comment: I am trying this solution friend.Once it is working fine then let you know and accept your answer.

Comment: have you tried?

Comment: any update? please let me know if any errors? found. it will use full someone if clarify this one.

Comment: Sorry for late reply.Actually It was given me some errors.So I just used bundle product detail page code snippet for it.This is i used for my question. [<input  type="checkbox" class="" name="bundle_option[<?php echo $option_id ?>][<?php echo $product_id ?>]" value="" prcvalue="<?php echo $opt_item_price ?>" />]

Comment: Here [    name="bundle_option[<?php echo $option_id ?>][<?php echo $product_id ?>]"    ] and [    prcvalue="<?php echo $opt_item_price ?>   ] is important.

Comment: was it working? or else update your thread with errors. So that it will understand here not clear your comment.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error now because I closed that issue.In the above I just set the input field name for form in the same order (how magento expect for bundle product add to cart) and set (custom) price parameter.

Answer (score 5):

Create a Controller

```
<?php

namespace Company\Module\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Json as ResultJson;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart;

class Addtocart extends Action
{
    /**
     * @var ProductFactory
     */
    private $productFactory;
    /**
     * @var Cart
     */
    private $cart;
    /**
     * @var FormKey
     */
    private $formKey;
    /**
     * @var JsonFactory
     */
    private $resultJsonFactory;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param FormKey $formKey
     * @param JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory
     * @param Cart $cart
     * @param ProductFactory $productFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        FormKey $formKey,
        JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
        Cart $cart,
        ProductFactory $productFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->formKey = $formKey;
        $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
        $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
        $this->cart = $cart;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return ResultJson
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
        $resultData = [
            'status' => 'success',
            'status_code' => 1,
            'message' => __('Products Added successfully.')
        ];

        $result = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
        $qty = 1;

        $product = $this->productFactory->create()->load($productId);
        $productsArray = $this->getBundleOptions($product);
        $params = [
            'product' => $productId,
            'bundle_option' => $productsArray,
            'qty' => $qty
        ];

        try {
            /**
             * Add bundle product in cart
             */
            if ($product->getId()) {
                $this->cart->addProduct($product, $params);
                $this->cart->save();
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $resultData = [
                'status' => 'fail',
                'status_code' => 0,
                'message' => __('Unable to add the Product. Exception ' . $e->getMessage())
            ];
            return $result->setData($resultData);
        }
        return $result->setData($resultData);
    }

    /**
     * get all the selection products used in bundle product
     * @param $product
     * @return mixed
     */
    private function getBundleOptions(Product $product)
    {
        $selectionCollection = $product->getTypeInstance()
            ->getSelectionsCollection(
                $product->getTypeInstance()->getOptionsIds($product),
                $product
            );
        $bundleOptions = [];
        foreach ($selectionCollection as $selection) {
            $bundleOptions[$selection->getOptionId()][] = $selection->getSelectionId();
        }
        return $bundleOptions;
    }
}
```

Comment: Very helpful, three years later. Got me over a hump. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me (Magento 2.2.6):

```
$product = $this->_productRepository->getById($id, false, null, true);
$this->_cart->addProduct($product, $data);
```

where `$data` is an array as shown below:

```
$data = [
    'qty' => 1,
    'product' => 45,
    'bundle_option' => [
        1 => 4,
        2 => 8, 
        3 => 2,
        4 => 7,
    ],
    'bundle_option_qty' => [
        1 => 1,
        2 => 4, 
        3 => 2,
        4 => 14,
    ]
];
```

the keys inside `bundle_option` and `bundle_option_qty` are indexes, not some ID's. I reckon it doesn't matter what these keys are as long as they correspond to the keys in the other array.

Items inside `bundle_option` array are options ID's and the other contains quantities so in this case we add 1 item ID=4, 4 items ID=8 and so on...

Comment: This saved me time, thanks for the correct answer to the data format

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit late to the party, but I was struggling with the same issue myself. There were a few bundle products with required attributes. In order to tackle this in my case, a seperate product attribute called "is_fixed_bundle" was created, and the below code was used to be able to add the product to cart including its required options from the catalog list, based on some of the answers used in this question. So, for people reading this and those who are working on Magento 2.3+, this might help.

app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\AbstractType">
        <plugin disabled="false" name="Vendor_Module_Plugin_Magento_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_AbstractType" sortOrder="10" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\AbstractType"/>
    </type>

    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add">
        <plugin disabled="false" name="Vendor_Module_Plugin_Magento_Checkout_Controller_Cart_Add" sortOrder="10" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Create the plugins:
app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/Magento/Catalog/Model/Product/Type/AbstractType.php

```php
<?php
/**
 * Copyright ©  All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type;

class AbstractType
{

    /**
     * There are some bundle products with attribute "is_fixed_bundle" indicating this product
     * contains required products in its bundle, magento by default does not allow adding these bundles
     * to cart without specifying the bundle products.
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\AbstractType $subject
     * @param $result
     * @param $product
     * @return bool
     */
    public function afterIsPossibleBuyFromList(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\AbstractType $subject,
        $result,
        $product
    ) {
        // check if result initially is false, because we only want to double-check then
        // please note this needs to have product attribute "is_fixed_bundle"
        if (!$result && $product->hasIsFixedBundle() && (bool) $product->getIsFixedBundle()) {
            return true;
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Next is the Add plugin, which is a beforePlugin on the add to cart route:

```php
<?php
/**
 * Copyright ©  All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\{ProductFactory, Product};

class Add
{
    /**
     * @var ProductFactory
     */
    private $productFactory;

    /**
     * @param ProductFactory $productFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
         ProductFactory $productFactory
    )
    {
        $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add $subject
     * @return array
     */
    public function beforeExecute(
        \Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add $subject
    ) {
        $requestParams = $subject->getRequest()->getParams();
        // we already have bundle option, meaning we're on product detail page, skip further processing of bundle options
        if (isset($requestParams['bundle_option'])) {
            return [];
        }
        $productId = (int)$subject->getRequest()->getParam('product');
        $product = $this->productFactory->create()->load($productId);
        if ($product && $product->hasIsFixedBundle() && (bool) $product->getIsFixedBundle()) {
            $bundleOptions['bundle_option'] = $this->getBundleOptions($product);
            $subject->getRequest()->setParams(array_merge($requestParams, $bundleOptions));
        }
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * get all the selection products used in bundle product
     * @param $product
     * @return mixed
     */
    private function getBundleOptions(Product $product)
    {
        $selectionCollection = $product->getTypeInstance()
            ->getSelectionsCollection(
                $product->getTypeInstance()->getOptionsIds($product),
                $product
            );
        $bundleOptions = [];
        foreach ($selectionCollection as $selection) {
            $bundleOptions[$selection->getOptionId()][$selection->getProductId()] = $selection->getSelectionId();
        }
        return $bundleOptions;
    }
}
```

A thing to note, the usage of `->load()` is deprecated and should be replaced by using the product resource model.
Parts of this module was created using [mage2gen](https://mage2gen.com/), thanks to @Devendra Gupta for the getBundleOptions() method.

Comment: Doesn't work for me - Magento 2.3.2

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try like below.

```
$product = $this->productRepository->getById("29");
$magento = array(21=>"1",22 => "2", 23 => "3");
$par = array('product' => $product->getId(),
             'bundle_options' => array(  1 => $magento),
             'qty' => $qty);
$this->cart->addProduct($_product,$par);
$this->cart->save();
```

`$magento` parameters **21,22,23** are child product ids

`$par` should be below screenshot.

[image]

And finally Bundle product should configure the like below screenshot other wise it won't work.

[image]

Now run the above code it will add the bundle product to cart.

Feel free to ask if you have any queries.

Comment: Isn't it 'bundle_option' ? You write 'bundle_options'

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented in the following way,

1. i have add to cart url like this:

   ```
   $cartHelper = $this->helper('Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart');
   $addToCartUrl = $cartHelper->getAddUrl($product);
   ```
2. If the the product type is bundle, then get the bundle options as magento requires to add it to cart.

   `$productBundleOptions = $product->getProductOptions()['info_buyRequest'];`
3. then add a form with hidden values of bundle options in phtml file like this :

   ```
    <form data-role="tocart-form" action="<?php echo $addToCartUrl; ?>" method="post">
                   <?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey')?>
                   <div class="btn">
                       <button type="submit" title="Add to Cart" class="action tocart primary">
                           <span>Add to Cart</span>
                       </button>
                   </div>
                   <?php
                       $bundleOptionArray = $productBundleOptions['bundle_option'];
                       foreach ($bundleOptionArray as $bundleOptionArrayKey => $bundleOptionArrayValue) { ?>
                           <input type="hidden" class="bundle-option-<?= $bundleOptionArrayKey ?>  product bundle option" name="bundle_option[<?= $bundleOptionArrayKey ?>]" value="<?= $bundleOptionArrayValue ?>" id="bundle-option-<?= $bundleOptionArrayKey."-".$bundleOptionArrayValue ?>" checked="checked" aria-required="true">
                       <?php } ?>
               </form>
   ```

Comment: Hi Use this code but it adds only one item of bundle product in cart. please can you give me the solution. @TS Guhan

Answer (score -1):

Please find below code I have used for add to cart bundle product programmatically.

The **`$this->_product`** property is an object of **`\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product`**

The **`$this->cartManagementInterface`** property is an object of **`\Magento\Quote\Api\CartManagementInterface`**

The **`$this->cartRepositoryInterface`** property is an object of **`\Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface`**

```
$cartId = $this->cartManagementInterface->createEmptyCart(); //Create empty cart

$quote = $this->cartRepositoryInterface->get($cartId);

$qty = 2;

$items = $orderData->getAllItems();

foreach ($items as $innerItem) {

    if ($innerItem->getProductType() == 'bundle' ){
            $product = $this->_product->load($innerItem->getProductId());
            $buyRequest = $innerItem->getProductOptionByCode('info_buyRequest');
            $buyRequest = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject($buyRequest);
            $buyRequest->setQty($qty);
            $quote->addProduct($product, $buyRequest);
        }
}
```