# Need help customizing the magento core code to add custom options to bundle product

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, custom-options, bundle-product

Is there a way to choose a specific custom option/customizable option of a simple product while adding the simple product to the Bundle product?

I need help in customizing the magento core code to add custom options to bundle product.

Already referred [Magento 2 - Is it possible to enable "Customizable Options" feature in Bundle products?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/283349/magento-2-is-it-possible-to-enable-customizable-options-feature-in-bundle-pr)

Comment: By default Bundled products do not allow simple products with custom options.
You would need a customization for that.

Comment: Please check this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/356873/82670 this works for configurable products. To show the custom option you need to customize it.

Comment: You can check this solution, might be helpful for your. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/146745/how-to-add-bundle-product-to-cart-programmatically-with-custom-price-and-quantit